# 301 redirect based on file extension to a new extension

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

My current URI is `http://example.com/blog/clients/clientname/?file=media.flv`.

I need all hits to that exact URI structure to 301 to the same structure but change the file extension to `MP4`.

What are the htaccess rules I need to setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code in .htaccess should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(file=.*)\.flv [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%1.MP4 [L,R=301]
```

Remember you cannot match QUERY_STRING in RewriteRule.

`NC` flag is for ignore case comparison, you can remove it if you don't need it.